# Cron queue not working

Tags: 7, cron, queue

I'm trying to set up a cron queue, but for some reason, I don't manage to get this done.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function mymodule_cron() {
    // Setup the queue
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get('import_jobs');
    // Create cache
    drupal_flush_all_caches();
}

function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
    $queues['import_jobs'] = array(
    'worker callback' => '_import_all_jobs',
    'time' => 15, 
    );
    return $queues;
}
```

The `_import_all_jobs` function does it's work excellent, so nothing wrong with that. I use the [Ultimate Cron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) module and my cron job is listed over there:

[image]

But for some reason, nothing happens... So I'm wondering what I do wrong...

Comment: Have you actually got Cron running on the server?

Comment: Yes, I've got Cron running on the server

Answer (score 3):

You need to [add items to your queue](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/function/DrupalQueueInterface%3a%3acreateItem/7). You have created a queue, but haven't added anything to it, so nothing is being done.

```
$queue->createItem($item);
```

`$item` will get passed to the queue callback function (`_import_all_jobs`).

I would suggest modifying `_import_all_jobs` to import an individual job (`_import_job`). Then `$item` would be a job added to the queue and you let DrupalQueue do its thing.

This article may be helpful: [Cron Queues: Processing large amounts of data in cron](http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/randall-knutson/cron-queues-processing-large-amounts-data-cron)

And here is some relevant Drupal documentation: [Queue operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7)

Comment: That's what I figured, but what would the `$item` be? I don't need an array or something similar. All I need is the function `_import_all_jobs` to run on a cron job.

Comment: In that case, it can be anything you want, like NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not processing multiple items, you could just run `_import_all_jobs` from the cron:

```
function mymodule_cron() {
    _import_all_jobs();

    // Create cache
    drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

But it seems like `_import_all_jobs` is doing multiple things and should be modified to work as a DrupalQueue, as I've suggested in my first answer.